# H2 database: referring to a table in root schema from a foreign key constraint

Tags: java, sql, database, h2

Given a table in root schema:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    username VARCHAR(50),
    password VARCHAR(50));
```

and a table in `Quiz` schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Quiz.Results (
    username VARCHAR(50),
    points INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES user(username));
```

I'm unable to actually create the foreign key, because the database claims the table `user` does not actually exist. Neither can I subsequently add the foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE QUIZ.RESULTS
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES user (username)
```

Both tables are, of course, stored in the same database.

Since this is just a piece of homework, I'm more than happy to simply skip adding a foreign key. But I'm curious if this is indeed a limitation in H2, a bug, or if it works as intended.

Can I somehow refer to table `user` outside the `quiz` schema?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You would need to explicitly set the schema name if you refer to a table in a different schema. The default schema name for H2 is `public`. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
    username VARCHAR(50),
    password VARCHAR(50));
create schema quiz;
CREATE TABLE Quiz.Results (
    username VARCHAR(50),
    points INT, 
    FOREIGN KEY (username) 
    REFERENCES public.user(username));
```

To create the foreign key constraint later, use:

```
ALTER TABLE QUIZ.RESULTS
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (username) 
    REFERENCES public.user(username) ;
```

Comment: Knowing the default schema (what I called the 'root schema') name helped. Thanks!

Comment: Can I ask why you're adding the `FOREIGN KEY (username)` twice? It seems you add it once in the table definition for `Quiz.Results`, then a second time in your `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Comment: @CraigOtis You are right, it should be either one or the other. I changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

yes very much possible. You need to use corresponding Schema name for both tables.

suppose your defualt schema name is `DefaultSchema` then your query will be

```
ALTER TABLE QUIZ.RESULTS
ADD FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES DefaultSchema.user (username)
```